# how to get the userID on a beforeSave function in parse.com cloud code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a beforeSave function in parse.com cloud code.

I need to get the userID of the user sending the request. it is not stored in the object I'm sending . In the cloud code console, I can see the line:

```
E2014-10-08T00:41:30.099Z] v71: before_save triggered for Bill for user 9obpDIgerJ
```

so the userID is somewhere there, but I can't figure out where to get it!

thank you

Comment: maybe try _objectId_ on the object you are saving.  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on the Cloud Code [Calling a Cloud Function documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide?language=JavaScript#functions-calling), request.user contains the Parse.User that is making the request